# Add dynamic input boxes in a Symfony form

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony

### What I want to do

I'm trying to build a form in `Symfony 2.8` that requests the user's choice between many types of credentials and add an input box to the form it's similar to this [one](http://www.formget.com/script-preview/?preview_url=http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/createdynamicformJS/getform.html) but I use a select option field instead of buttons.

### What I did

I was able to create this form with HTML and JavaScript.The user can select more than one credential type only once except the OTV Option that can be selected without limits.
[image here](http://snag.gy/MSxNY.jpg)

### What's my problem

I need a way to store user's data in a session and get them in my controller.
Is it possible to pass submitted data from HTML form to a Symfony controller and if not how can I build a similar form with Symfony's formBuilder ?

Comment: take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Thanks I'm giving this a try but I want to know first if there is any way to transmit data from a HTML form can I save them in a random object in twig and then get them in the controller ?

Answer (score 1):

CollectionType is probably what you are looking for.

For your purposes, you can think of it as adding rows to the end of a two-column list. The Left Column has credential_type with Name, Email etc in a `<select>`; and the Right Column allows for your text values.

You'll have two FormTypes: one for the list, and another for the list item. In the list item FormType, you should be able to set a CallbackConstraint to validate e.g. that email values are valid upon form submission.

All user changes are saved at the same time, only when the form as valid.

Comment: Thanks this is a part of the solution but how can I dynamically generate input boxes and respect the conditions ( zero or one selection for every option and zero or more for OTV )

Comment: The list FormType will create a HTML prototype which will appear when the user clicks "Add" or similar - the cookbook article describes this.

Comment: You can check you have all the items you need in your controller when the form is Valid, and then make it invalid if things are missing

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that. There is `CollectionType` in Symfony form. You can read about it [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) and how to implement it [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

P.S. The main problem in this case is to generate specific names for dynamically created fields to provide a normal handling data in controller.

Comment: Thanks.. this may be a part of the solution